# AngularJS: Two-column odd/even layout

Tags: css, angularjs, onsen-ui, responsive

Having a problem trying to get a repeating two-column layout in AngularJS. My dataset is a JSON object of image information. I want to show a two column layout of images. No matter what I tweak, something is wrong in my odd/even logic, but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.left {
    float: left !important;
    width: 50% !important;
}
.right {
    float: right !important;
    width: 50% !important;
}
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left,
    .right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="issue in issues">
  <div ng-if="$even" class="group">
    <div class="left" ng-if="$even">
      <img src="{{ issue.image }}" ng-src="{{ issue.image }}">
    </div>
    <div class="right" ng-if="$odd">
      <img src="{{ issue.image }}" ng-src="{{ issue.image }}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with code is you had wrap your logic inside

```
<div ng-if="$even" class="group">
```

Div which is restricting to show odd logic div.

instead of having two different div, I'd say use `ngClassEven` & `ngClassOdd` directive. Also remove the wrapper div which has `ng-if="$even"` condition.

```
<div ng-repeat="issue in issues">
    <div ng-class-even="'left'" ng-class-odd="'right'">
        <img ng-src="{{ issue.image }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for appreciation! Cheers;)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... Amazing, thank you Pankaj!

Comment: Pleased to help you, Thanks ;)

Comment: Pankaj, Is there any reason to use `src` and `ng-src` together?

Comment: Not at alll.. forgot to remove

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already got your answer, but still here are some alternatives which may prove useful:

1. Simply ng-class - it's a little more flexible, so you may find it useful in other cases too. In this case:

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="issue in issues" ng-class="{left: $even, right: $odd}">
     <img ng-src="{{ issue.image }}">
   </div>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="issue in issues" ng-class="$even ? 'left' : 'right'">
     <img ng-src="{{ issue.image }}">
   </div>
   ```

   Note that unlike some other properties `ng-class` can coexist with `class` in harmony so you could also add `class="item"` or something similar.
2. Since it's a styling issue you may want to try to solve it in css. As long as you think IE 6-8 should die you can use the `nth-child` selector:

   ```
   :nth-child(odd) { ... }
   :nth-child(event) { ... }
   ```

Also since both my and Pankaj's answers removed your `group` class here is some simpler css which you could use instead:

```
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.left {
    clear: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .item {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Or again if you're not all about IE you could use flexbox (which removes the need for **any** JS):

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .item {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```